# Allowing public-read and bucket-owner-full-control in S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a bucket of images public read even when uploaded from another AWS account. I have the current bucket policy in place:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works great when I upload using credentials from the primary account, but when I upload from the other account added by ACL it doesn't apply. As I read I found that you can add `bucket-owner-full-control` or `public-read` but not both. My end goal is to allow the object to be fully accesses by both AWS accounts AND have public read access on upload. Is this possible (ideally without two requests)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it seems you can only specify one ACL when creating an object in Amazon S3.

For details of what each Canned ACL means, see: [Canned ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl)

For details of how ownership works, see: [Amazon S3 Bucket and Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html#about-resource-owner)

Personally, I would not recommend using ACLs to control access. They are a hold-over from the early days of Amazon S3. These days, I would recommend using a **Bucket Policy** if you wish to make a large number of objects public, especially if they are in the same bucket/path.

Thus, an object can be uploaded with `bucket-owner-full-control` and the Bucket Policy can make them publicly accessible.

Comment: thanks for your answer it pointed me to a new direction to solve my problem, but I have to point out two mistakes here for others: 1) the canned acl name is `bucket-owner-full-control` not `bucket-owner-full-access`, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl for the whole list. 2) if you are using `bucket-owner-full-control` it's very likely you are trying to upload to an S3 bucket that from a different account. unfortunately, in this case, the uploaded file's owner is not the same as the owner of the bucket, the bucket policy can't fully control it

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the ACL name.

Comment: "They are a hold-over from the early days of Amazon S3. These days, I would recommend using a Bucket Policy " too bad that doesn't work if you are uploading from a different account than the owner

Answer (score 2):

The above accepted answer is incorrect as S3 bucket policies are ignored on objects published from another account.

The correct way to apply multiple ACLs on a cross account publish is like follows:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive blahdir s3://bucketname/blahdir/ --cache-control public,max-age=31536000 --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers full=id=S3_ACCOUNT_CANONICAL_ID
```

Comment: Although this does not transfer ownership like `bucket-owner-full-control`, does it? It just grants full access to the new bucket's owner (which may be enough).